# How to make Xcode IDE respect CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.6, xcode4.6.3

I can provide **CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR** to *xcodebuild* CLI, but how to do this from within IDE?

- I did set **Project/Workspace Settings** -> **Derived Data Location** to **Project-relative**.
- At **Advanced** I picked **Custom** and **Relative to Workspace**
  checked)

That gives me **almost** what I want, but product (**.app**) is within **Debug** directory (for *Debug Configuration*)

> @some_relative_path/Debug/Product

What I want is:

> @some_relative_path/Product

Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just a matter of setting:

> ***TARGET***->**Build Settings**->**Build Locations**->**Per-configuration Build Product Path**